# /usr/bin/pg no longer present in 18.04 util-linux package

Tags: package-management, 18.04

I just upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04.

The /usr/bin/pg command was present in 16.04, in the util-linux (2.27.1) package.

/usr/bin/pg is not present in 18.04, and not in util-linux (2.31.1.0) package.

Has "pg" been dropped, or moved to another package, or ....???

And how could I research the answer to that question...?

Comment: Reviewing the ChangeLog for util-linux shows this in the "util-linux (2.29.2-2)" change:    * Stop shipping the deprecated 'pg' utility
                 * Revert "Explicitly (re)enable deprecated pg utility"
So I guess my question changes to is "pg" available in any other packages?

Comment: It looks like a less-functional `less`. Why not use `less`?

Comment: I guess I'll have to start using "less"... I've been using pg for about thirty years, so the hands knew what to do without thinking...

Comment: You can make an alias and continue typing `pg`

Comment: Yeah, but the navigation commands differ... I'll just have to get used to "less"... that's not really a bad thing...

Comment: Since you're trying out new things, [you can also try out `most`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81129/what-are-the-differences-between-most-more-and-less#comment119919_81131)  if you feel like it.

Comment: Installed most and looked at man page... displays binary too... nice.  thanks for the tip.